# How to leave empty space on the right in tradingchart

Tags: graphics, finance

The Tradingchart function is very useful, although tremendously graphics heavy. For better understanding of the image I would like to leave a white space on the right but it is ignored. For example.
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2022, 5, 1}, {2022, 12, 31}}];
TradingChart[data]
Leaves nothing on the right, PlotRange is ignored.
Let me explain further. I would like a TradingChart of type

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: Do you want the white space to be inside of the frame, or on the outside? I.e. do you want to set `PlotRange`, or `ImagePadding`?

Comment: Inside. I tried both Istruction but the chart was unchanged